# Issues with theme on moving drupal website to new server

Tags: installation

I have never used drupal before, and just have been tasked with moving a drupal website to a new server. I've moved the files and database successfully - had a bit of a fight with clean urls which were a pain to switch off, new host did not have them enabled.

The website is mostly working fine, except themes. Anything theme related (images etc) is not loading. If the direct url of a theme item is placed into the browser address bar it is opened successfully. I have a feeling its to do with the first item after the temporary address of the new server, the /~balliolj part, but have no clue where to fix this.

Old website: http://www.ballioljcr.org/
New website: `http://31.193.134.90/~balliolj/`

I'm trying to get everything working as before prior to moving the domain, hence the temp address.

Any input on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

At https://groups.drupal.org/node/104694 having a tilde in the url was successfully solved usign RewriteBase /~user on the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please use HTTP Fox on Firefox browser to check if they are 404 errors.
2. If you find 404 errors then it is understood that images are missing from the theme's directory.
3. To solve: Just open a working website and save the images to your local machine.
4. Upload the downloaded images to the same directories on your new server.
5. Once this is done, flush the drupal site cache once.
6. Images will show-up.